# C++ calling a template function from another template function

Tags: c++, templates

I just tried the following code

```
class MailBox{
};

 template<typename T>
     void foo(T){
     cout << "In foo" << endl;
 }

template<typename T>
 void foo1(T){
     foo(T);
 }

 main()
 {
         MailBox m;
         std::vector<MailBox> m1;

         foo1(m1);
 }
```

We are getting below error while compilation

```
test1.cpp: In function âvoid foo1(T)â:
test1.cpp:15: error: expected primary-expression before â)â token
```

Any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing formal parameters:

```
 template<typename T>
     void foo(T t) {
         cout << "In foo" << endl;
 }

 template<typename T>
     void foo1(T t) {
         foo(t);
 }
```

Comment: to be precise, the formal parameter is only needed in `foo1`. You might even get "unused parameter" warnings if you provide one in `foo`.

Comment: @Arne: True - I was aiming for simplicity in the answer and also assuming that the real `foo` would eventually do something useful with its parameter, but you are correct, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting the names of the parameters!

For instance, `foo1()` should look like this:

```
template <typename T>
  foo1 (T myT) {
    foo(myT);
  }
```

Remember that template'd types are still types, and you need to use them to declare things (like variables) of those types.